# Can't read Bonus as a variable

Tags: c++, initialization

I have a code and it can't read Bonus as a variable.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char Bonus,Salary,TotalSalary;
    int num1, num2;

    cout <<"Enter the hours of work for week"<<endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout <<"Enter your hourly rate"<<endl;
    cin >>num2;

    Salary = num1 * num2;

    if (Bonus >= 45)
        cout <<"Your bonus is 500 pesos"<<endl;
    else if (Bonus>40&&Bonus<=45)
        cout <<"Your bonus is 250 pesos"<<endl;
    else if (Bonus>45&&Bonus<=40)
        cout <<"Your bonus is 150 pesos"<<endl;

    TotalSalary=Salary + Bonus;

    cout <<"Your basic salary is" <<Salary <<"with a bonus of" <<Bonus <<"and a           total of"<<TotalSalary<<endl; 

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I hope you can help me with my problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you set the `Bonus` field? Are you expecting user to input it?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't read it as numeric value from `cin`? Also why did you declare these variables as `char`?

Comment: `Bonus` has not been assigned a value, so any code that uses it will produce nonsense. Also, it's generally not a good idea to use `char` variables to hold integer values. It works, but for salaries, etc., they don't have a big enough range.

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ones that include a description of the problems you are having.

Comment: Sorry sir, if this i'm just a newbie ill try to do better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `Bonus` and  `Salary` and `TotalSalary` variable is a `char`. So you must declare them as an `int` variable. And `Bonus` is used without having been initialized, which invokes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior, so you can initialize it to `0`. Also, you have to ask the user to input the `Bonus` by

```
cout <<"Enter the Bonus"<<endl;
cin >> Bonus;
```

And it should work.

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int Salary,TotalSalary;
int num1, num2, Bonus = 0;

cout <<"Enter the hours of work for week"<<endl;
cin >> num1;
cout <<"Enter your hourly rate"<<endl;
cin >>num2;

cout <<"Enter the Bonus"<<endl;
cin >> Bonus;


Salary = num1 * num2;

if (Bonus >= 45)
cout <<"Your bonus is 500 pesos"<<endl;
else if (Bonus>40&&Bonus<=45)
cout <<"Your bonus is 250 pesos"<<endl;
else if (Bonus>45&&Bonus<=40)
cout <<"Your bonus is 150 pesos"<<endl;

TotalSalary=Salary + Bonus;

cout <<"Your basic salary is " <<Salary <<" with a bonus of " <<Bonus <<" and a total of "<<TotalSalary<<endl; 

 system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work but can you help me with one more thing?My cout on the end is messed up aswell. I really appreciate your help

Comment: I have just updated it, please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with the code:

```
Salary = num1 * num2;
```

`Bonus`, `Salary` and `TotalSalary` are defined as `char`, while they should be defined as `int` too.

`Bonus` is used without having been initialized, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The compiler should have warned you about that. Make sure warnings are on and at the highest level.

---

Some details about your `if statements`:

```
if (Bonus >= 45)
    cout << "Your bonus is 500 pesos" << endl;
else if (Bonus>40 && Bonus<=45)
    // minor detail, but can't be equal to 45 again
    cout <<"Your bonus is 250 pesos" << endl;
else if (Bonus>45 && Bonus<=40)
    // mayor detail: can never be >45 *and* <=40 at the same time
    cout <<"Your bonus is 150 pesos" << endl;
```

You could change that to:

```
// You probably want to check Salary instead of Bonus?
// although the values (like 45) might be off
Salary = num1 * num2;

if (Salary >= 45)
    Bonus = 500;
else if (Salary > 40)
    Bonus = 250;
else
    Bonus = 150;

cout << "Your bonus is " << Bonus << " pesos" << endl;
```

**Full example**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int num1 = 0,
        num2 = 0,
        Bonus = 0,
        Salary = 0,
        TotalSalary = 0;

    cout << "Enter the hours of work for week: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter your hourly rate: ";
    cin >> num2;

    Salary = num1 * num2;

    // values (like 45) might be off here
    if      (Salary >= 45)  Bonus = 500;
    else if (Salary > 40)   Bonus = 250;
    else                    Bonus = 150;

    cout << "Your bonus is " << Bonus << " pesos" << endl;

    TotalSalary = Salary + Bonus;

    cout << "Your basic salary is " << Salary 
         << " with a bonus of "     << Bonus
         << " and a total of "      << TotalSalary << endl; 

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy! 
Where you define `Bonus` (type char)
Is declared but never defined before you test it in

```
if(Bonus>=45)
```

At that point your `char Bonus` may have any possible value given at runtime. 
There is no default assignment like Bonus = 0 or something like this.

Comment: You should polish your terminology a bit.

Comment: yes, it stands for "declaration", "definition" aso. thanks

Comment: You should have used the term _"initialization"_ instead of _"definition"_. The variable is as well declared and defined actually. Definition makes more sense for e.g. static member variables, that can be declared and must be defined separately.

Comment: Is right, thanks; I just think that the initialization of a variable occurs automatically when is declared but with a (random-like) value - the compiler will not complain if one let a variable "uninitialized". In this respect, a variable is just "defined" when "definitely" gets a given value (through assignment, indirection) - please correct if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 0):

`Bonus` doesn't have a value, and it's a `char`.

The type of your variables should be `int`, and I suspect that you want to set `Bonus` to a value dependent on `Salary`:

```
int Bonus = 0;
int Salary = 0;
int TotalSalary = 0;

// ...

if (Salary >= 45)
    Bonus = 500;
else if (Salary > 40)
    Bonus = 250;
else
    Bonus = 150;

TotalSalary = Salary + Bonus;
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. =)